# Updating cluster icon after updating children

Tags: leaflet, markerclusterer

In this contrived example, I'm showing temperature measurements on a map, and using the markercluster plugin to cluster markers that get too close. I'm using the iconCreateFunction of the cluster group to generate an icon that reflects the average temperature of the children in the group.

My problem is that I want to update the temperatures of the markers over time, and have the cluster icons update to reflect these changes. Is there any way to trigger the iconCreateFunction on all the clusters after an update?

Comment: trying to do pretty same thing. did you find how ? thx

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution which is a bit hacky, but does work:

if you have your marker group

```
var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup(...);
```

then you can force the clusters to update their icons by something like

```
for (var cluster in markers._featureGroup._layers) {
    markers._featureGroup._layers[cluster]._updateIcon && markers._featureGroup._layers[cluster]._updateIcon();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The "official" solution seems to be to re-add the marker to the clustergroup, as found here: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/287

this can be done simply with:

```
var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup(...);
...
markers.removeLayer(marker);
markers.addLayer(marker);
```